# MySQL top 2 records per group

Tags: mysql, sql

Basically I need to get only the last 2 records for each user, considering the last created_datetime:

```
id | user_id | created_datetime
1  | 34      | '2015-09-10'
2  | 34      | '2015-10-11'
3  | 34      | '2015-05-23'
4  | 34      | '2015-09-13'
5  | 159     | '2015-10-01'
6  | 159     | '2015-10-02'
7  | 159     | '2015-10-03'
8  | 159     | '2015-10-06'
```

Returns (expected output):

```
2  | 34      | '2015-10-11'
1  | 34      | '2015-09-10'
7  | 159     | '2015-10-03'
8  | 159     | '2015-10-06'
```

I was trying with this idea:

```
select user_id, created_datetime, 
$num := if($user_id = user_id, $num + 1, 1) as row_number, 
$id := user_id as dummy 
from logs group by user_id 
having row_number <= 2
```

The idea is keep only these top 2 rows and remove all the others.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is your query and expected output?

Comment: I was trying with this idea: 
select user_id, created_datetime,
      $num := if($user_id = user_id, $num + 1, 1) as row_number,
      $id := user_id as dummy
from logs
group by user_id
having row_number <= 2

The idea is keep only these top 2 rows and remove all the others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea is close.  I think this will work better:

```
select u.*
from (select user_id, created_datetime, 
             $num := if(@user_id = user_id, @num + 1,
                        if(@user_id := id, 1, 1)
                       ) as row_number
      from logs cross join
           (select @user_id := 0, @num := 0) params
      order by user_id 
     ) u
where row_number <= 2 ;
```

Here are the changes:

- The variables are set in only one expression.  MySQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions, so this is important.
- The work is done in a subquery, which is then processed in the outer query.
- The subquery uses `order by`, not `group by`.
- The outer query uses `where` instead of `having` (actually, in MySQL `having` would work, but `where` is more appropriate).

Comment: Cool, that's what I was expecting. Thank you very much!
Here it goes the last version with few adjustments:

set $num := 0, $user_id := 0;
select u.*
from (select user_id, created_datetime, 
             $num := if($user_id = user_id, $num + 1,
                        if($user_id := user_id, 1, 1)
                       ) as row_number
      from logs cross join
           (select $user_id := 0, $num := 0) params
      order by user_id DESC, created_datetime DESC
     ) u
where row_number <= 2

Comment: nice, but  had to change all $ to @ and `if(@user_id := id, 1, 1)` to `if(@user_id := user_id, 1, 1)` for it to work.

Comment: @GordonLinoff How would be if there was one more column to check? Example: field (field1, field2...), showing 2 records for each field and user?

Comment: Similar logic can be used.  The query would look a bit different though.  Feel free to ask another question.