# Getting invalid use of group function

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's my query

```
 Select email_address, count(order_id) AS order_count, (sum(item_price - discount_amount) * (quantity)) AS order_total, 
(avg(item_price - discount_amount) * (quantity)) AS avg_order_total
from customers join orders
using(customer_id)
join order_items
using(order_id)
group by customer_id > 1, email_address
```

[Output of my query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bK2W.png)

Output Expected

[image]

I'm trying to produce the wanted output but I'm not sure how to only display only 3 of them. Tried a where statement but it made it worst.

---

Another way to display output without the use of limit?

Here's my **REVISED** query

```
Select email_address, count(customer_id) AS order_count, sum((item_price - discount_amount) * (quantity)) AS order_total, 
round(avg((item_price - discount_amount) * (quantity)),2) AS avg_order_total
from customers join orders
using(customer_id)
join order_items
using(order_id)
group by customer_id 
order by count(customer_id) desc limit 3
```

I'm trying to produce the expected output without using limit but I can't figure how. Above is my query that I used limit on to display the result and it shows the output I wanted. I tried using a where statement, but it doesn't run my query when I did.

Comment: i dont think so you need group by since you already have count / sum

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says: "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function."

Comment: I don't believe you will find a better way to limit the results to 3 rows. Why do you want to avoid use of limit?

Comment: My instructor want it that way

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this query?

```
SELECT c.email_address,
count(o.order_id) AS order_count,
(sum(i.item_price - i.discount_amount) * (i.quantity)) AS order_total,
(avg(sum(i.item_price - i.discount_amount) * (i.quantity))) AS avg_order_total
from customers c
INNER JOIN orders o ON c.customer_id = o.customer_id
INNER JOIN order_items i ON o.order_id = i.order_id
GROUP BY email_address;
```

A few things to note:

- You need to include any field in the SELECT clause that isn't being aggregated into your GROUP BY. So, I've added email_address.
- It's far better to specify the actual columns being joined, instead of the USING keyword. This is because it's easier to maintain if any of the columns change.
- I've made some assumptions about which table your fields belong to and prefixed them with the table alias (c, o, or i). If this is wrong they can be changed. But it's better to use table aliases as it improves the maintainability of the code, and it's easier to read & write.

Comment: says order_id in field list is ambiguous

Comment: I've updated the answer to use aliases. I've made some assumptions about the columns. Does this query work?

Comment: What is your GROUP BY and SELECT clause now? Why did you edit it?

Answer (score 0):

There are several guesses in this suggestion:

```
SELECT
      c.email_address
    , COUNT(DISTINCT o.order_id)                                AS order_count
    , (SUM(oi.item_price - oi.discount_amount) * (oi.quantity)) AS order_total
    , (AVG(oi.item_price - oi.discount_amount) * (oi.quantity)) AS avg_order_total
FROM customers c
JOIN orders o ON c.customer_id = o.customer_id
JOIN order_items oi ON o.order_id = oi.order_id
WHERE c.customer_id > 1
GROUP BY
      c.email_address
```

When joining several tables it is good practice to nominate which table a column comes from. To make this brief each table can be given an alias and a common method for that is to use first letters e.g. for this set of tables: c, o, oi

I may have guessed incorrectly when placing the aliases in some places and I cannot fix that as I don't know your tables.

+EDIT
By the way, I also included `DISTINCT` into the count of orders, if you don't do that you are counting the number of order items instead.

---

```
SELECT
      c.email_address
    , COUNT(DISTINCT o.order_id)                                AS order_count
    , (SUM(oi.item_price - oi.discount_amount) * (oi.quantity)) AS order_total
    , (SUM(oi.item_price - oi.discount_amount) * (oi.quantity)) 
      / COUNT(DISTINCT o.order_id)                              AS avg_order_total
FROM customers c
JOIN orders o ON c.customer_id = o.customer_id
JOIN order_items oi ON o.order_id = oi.order_id
WHERE c.customer_id > 1
GROUP BY
      c.email_address
```

Comment: oi? Cant run it, says unknown column oi.item_price in field list

Comment: **Which table is item_price from?** (I don't know, so I guessed order_items which I gave the alias oi). Please re-read my answer too as I discussed this very pint as you commented.

Comment: c for customers, oi for order_id, and o for orders

Comment: c for customers, o for orders and oi for order_items (OOOPs I forgot to include that alias in the query, just fixed that)

Comment: It runs but the output isn't what I wanted

Comment: have another look please I added a second query

Comment: Still not the output I wanted

Comment: **YIKES!** You can't change the question to that extent. That's bad. All responses prior to that edit are now irrelevant. What you should have done is either ask a new question or add a new "section" to this question.  Is the only thing you now need the limit? (i.e. is everything else working?)

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, and yes just need the limit not to be used

Comment: Why? I dont think you can AND get only those 3 rows.

Comment: OK, in MySQL you can use the approach used here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33093017/mysql-top-2-records-per-group but you only need @num because you only need to create a ordered row number. For other databases that support it use ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by ...) instead. Do this in a subquery and then use a where clause in the outermost query  (as you see in that URL).