# How to get TopN query group by month MYSQL

Tags: mysql

There's a table like:

```
months  contact   COUNT
202007  asdas      45
202007  madhouse    1
202007  RORC YANG   1
202007  RORG        2
202007  ROR         5
202008  SARINA      1
202008  SMB         1
```

How can I get top 4 query result each month?

Expected result:

```
months  contact   COUNT
202007  asdas      45
202007  ROR         5
202007  RORG        2
202008  SARINA      1
202008  SMB         1
```

I'm working with `mysql5.6`

Comment: Is the first table shown the result of a query? Can you add that query to the question please?  what happens if all counts are 1 but there are 6 rows per month? do you display all 6 rows or cut-off at 4 rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are 2 choices. The first uses `rank() over()` which does not guarantee only 4 rows per month (there could be more) and the second uses `row_number() over()` which will limit number of rows to a max of 4 per month

```
select
    *
from (
      select
          * , rank() over(partition by months order by c desc) as cr
      from (
        select  months, contact, count(*) as c
        from mytable
        group by months, contact
        ) as g
    ) as d
where cr <= 4
;

select
    *
from (
      select
          * , row_number() over(partition by months order by c desc) as rn
      from (
        select  months, contact, count(*) as c
        from mytable
        group by months, contact
        ) as g
    ) as d
where rn <= 4
;
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/d2YtRy2mS28zdq7orExvjz/0)

for older MySQL try a row number hack:

```
select
    *
from (
      select
            @row_num :=IF(@prev_value=g.months,@row_num+1,1)AS RowNumber
          , g.months
          , g.contact
          , g.c
          , @prev_value := g.months
      from (
        select  months, contact, count(*) as c
        from mytable
        group by months, contact
        ) as g
      CROSS JOIN (SELECT @row_num :=1,  @prev_value :='') vars
      ORDER BY g.months, g.contact
    ) as d
where RowNumber <= 4
```

see that in [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jwwtTFgNGhJgZcrA6nU3nP/0)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I'm working with  low version `mysql5.6`.How to do with that

Comment: What a pity such a restriction wasn't mentioned in the question. That is much harder and requires something of a "hack" but has been in widespread use for a long time. e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33093017/mysql-top-2-records-per-group

Comment: added older MySQL row number hack example

Answer (score 0):

TOP5

```
SELECT z.months, z.contact, z.count
FROM
(SELECT
x.*,
@rownum := @rownum + 1,
IF(@part = x.months,@r := @r + 1,@r := 1) AS rank,
@part := x.months
FROM
(
SELECT
*
FROM
my_table e
ORDER BY
e.months ASC,e.count DESC) X,
(
SELECT
@rownum := 0,
@part := NULL,
@r := 0) rt)z
WHERE z.rank <=5
```